# How to have XMLForest returning all columns of a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a lot of columns (e.g : Column1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4, ...)

I'd like to use XMLElement and XMLForest function to generate an XML with each column being a tag.

I'm only able to do this by manually adding each column in the XMLForest : 
e.g :

```
SELECT
XMLElement("ParentTag", 
    XMLForest(TABLE.Column1, 
              TABLE.Column2,
              TABLE.Column2,
              ...)
)
FROM ...
```

Results :

```
<ParentTag> <Column1>Value1</Column1> <Column2>Value2</Column2> ...</ParentTag>
```

However i'd like to avoid typing each column as their number could increase in the future.

How can i do something like this ? :

```
SELECT
XMLElement("ParentTag", 
    XMLForest(TABLE.*)
)
FROM ...
```

Comment: did you try that:
 select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from all_objects') from dual;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `PLSQL` procedure to get your requirement done. Here in the `PLSQL` procedure, it would accept a `Tablename` and then generate the `XMLForest` and show the result. See below:

```
-- Creating a type of XMLTYPE
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Outpt IS TABLE OF XMLTYPE;
/

--Procedure with In parameter as Tablename and out parameter as resultset
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XM_FOREST (tabnm VARCHAR2, v_out IN OUT Outpt)
AS
   var     VARCHAR2 (4000);
   v_sql   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT cname
               FROM col
              WHERE tname = tabnm)
   LOOP
      var := var || ',' || i.cname;
   END LOOP;

   var := LTRIM (var, ',');

   v_sql :=
         'select XMLElement("ParentTag",XMLForest('
      || var
      || '  ) ) from  '
      || tabnm;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql BULK COLLECT INTO v_out;
END;

--------------

--Execution
DECLARE
   var_out   Outpt := Outpt ();
   LCLOB     CLOB;
BEGIN
   var_out.EXTEND;
   XM_FOREST (tabnm => 'EMPLOYEE', v_out => var_out);

   FOR i IN 1 .. var_out.COUNT
   LOOP
      LCLOB := var_out (i).getCLOBVAL ();
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (LCLOB);
   END LOOP;
END;
------
--Result

 SQL> /
    <ParentTag><EMPLOYEE_ID>1</EMPLOYEE_ID><FIRST_NAME>XXX</FIRST_NAME></ParentTag>
    <ParentTag><EMPLOYEE_ID>2</EMPLOYEE_ID><FIRST_NAME>YYY</FIRST_NAME></ParentTag>

 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can i do something like this ? :
>
> ```
> SELECT
> XMLElement("ParentTag", 
>     XMLForest(TABLE.*)
> )
> FROM ...
> ```

You cannot, you will have to type out all the names individually.

You could generate the query using dynamic SQL

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2982c/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id NUMBER,
  a  NUMBER,
  b  NUMBER,
  c  NUMBER,
  d  NUMBER
);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT '
SELECT XMLElement(
         "ParentTag", 
         XMLForest( '
         || LISTAGG( '"' || column_name || '"', ',' )
              WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY Column_id )
         ||' ) ) FROM ...' AS query
FROM   user_tab_columns
WHERE  table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2982c/3/0)**:

```
|                                                 QUERY |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| SELECT XMLElement(                                    |
|          "ParentTag",                                 |
|          XMLForest( "ID","A","B","C","D" ) ) FROM ... |
```

Comment: This worked but i prefered to use the PLSQL approach for reusability. Thank you for your help !